# Make sure command entered is Read Only

Tags: bash, security, read-only

I am creating an API that takes in any command (in bash) and executes it at the root. I want to ensure this command is RO and does not write anything. Any ideas of how to go about this? Maybe it can temporarily disabled with a timer or such?

Comment: Welcome to Super User @e22e22. You should [edit] your original post to include any additional information, rather than adding a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is possible. You could make sure that anything written to `stdout` or `stderr`, for example, gets redirected to `/dev/null`. However, if the utility wants to write to a file, there's no way that you can prevent or even know that.

Standard security practice is to never run untrusted programs with root privileges.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any way to, in the general case, ensure that a random program will not write anything anywhere. You are looking at something akin to solving [the halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), with a twist (stdout and stderr are exposed as file handles, too).

You could however create a small library that overrides the relevant handful of standard library calls, like creat(2), open(2), write(2) and some others, to not persist anything on disk. This would likely be something similar to [libfaketime](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85340/2465), and should be reasonably doable. It would be portable to any application through the LD_PRELOAD library preload mechanism of the dynamic loader.

However, that would almost certainly not be a full solution. *Especially* a process that runs as root could quite easily override any of that, if it knows to expect it and wants to do evil. For one thing, it depends on any such calls going through the common interfaces like the C library, which is not guaranteed; a process could just as easily copy the C library code directly into its own code. It could make direct calls to the kernel's syscall interfaces. The C library isn't some magical thing; it's userspace code like any other. And the binary could be statically linked, in which case the dynamic loader won't be invoked at all. It's probably possible to work around these limitations and prevent writes, but...

*Making write(2) and friends no-ops is also very likely to break things at some other end, when the process expects a file it wrote into to hold the data that was written.*

And what if it doesn't really write anything, but simply reads a couple of security-critical configuration files (/etc/crypttab, /etc/shadow, /etc/bind/rndc.key, ... you get the idea) and passes that data somewhere else; over the network, perhaps, or dumps it so that it becomes accessible through a side-channel attack?

I'd go one step further [than savanto](https://superuser.com/a/764202/53590). Standard security practice should be to not run untrusted software, period. And you *most definitely* should not run untrusted software as root. For anything that runs as root, you can put a couple of roadblocks in the way, but you *cannot* guarantee that it won't do whatever at all it wants to do. [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) can help, and probably goes quite a long way when used correctly, but is a beast to configure and it will likely make any policy violations lead to the call in question failing with an error condition and possibly a hard process abort, so it won't be graceful at all.

*The closest to what you seem to want to do that I can think of, which will work in the general case,* would be an isolated virtual machine with the capability of rolling back modifications made to the disk (usually referred to as snapshot rollback capability). That however will be far from seamless, and will come at a large overhead since you are for all intents and purposes running a second operating system instance, with all of what that means.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer, but I would look for **sandbox** or **virtual machine**.